# which is the best tool to show data from database table and apply update and delete on it

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have Xamarin.forms project which i am doing all the actions on Pcl i did my wcf rest client on pcl but i am showing them on grid. every thing is going like a charm but when debugging and showing results on the grid i am trying to select an item it doesnot allow to select , please lead me which is the best tool to show my datatable , i am thinking of listview and tableview, i am super new to xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm sorry for the poor english

It depends at each case. If you need to show a collection of data within you want to interact, maybe a ListView is a good option.

Take a look in [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/), this may clearify some things.

The best way to link your models to a view in this case is to use an ObservableCollection as the ItemSource of ListView. Thus, each selection at list items will provides the correspondent instance of YourType in this list.

Comment: its ok dont be and your English is very understandable as my english is also poor , thanks so much, yes i have a table with user name and password and usermobile.... so i want to show them and onclick on row i want to modify(update or delete) , i will take a look at observablecollection

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqF4G2kGFHI) can help you too. It's simple, short and objective pratical example.

Comment: I forgot to tell you have to be familiar with the Binding concepts as well. [Here is](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/) some usefull information.